# MySQL INSERT error after deploying to Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

I have a PHP app deployed on Heroku. I basically switched over from MAMP to Heroku. I followed the steps to set up MySQL in Heroku and successfully imported my tables over to the db on Heroku. I have no trouble extracting data from the db, but the INSERT is giving me this error

Error:INSERT INTO form (Ename, Stat, Id, IName, Class, Cn Term, Year, Total_hour, IClass_hours, Office_hours, Grading_hours, Other_hours, Position) VALUES ('', '','','','', , '', , 130,0, 0, 0, 0, '')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', , 130,0, 0, 0, 0, '')' at line 1

This is the code

```
sql = "INSERT INTO form ('Ename', 'Stat', 'Id', 'IName', 'Class', 'Cn', 'Term', Year, Total_hour, IClass_hours, Office_hours, Grading_hours, Other_hours, 'Position') VALUES ('$eName', '$CurrStudent','$Id','$iName','$CourseID', $CRN, '$Term', $Year, $Total_Hours,$Inclass_Duties, $Office_Duties, $Marking_Hours, $Other_Hours, '$position')";
```

This exact statement worked before, when I was using MAMP. I tried printing out the individual values and they're not working either
Edit: I'm using ClearDB

Comment: You should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. Your error doesn´t corresponde with your query. In the error, you missed at least one comma in **Class, Cn Term, Year** between Cn & Term. In your query, you should use back ticks for the column names `Ename` instead of 'Ename'

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. Are your columns actually quoted?